# MySQL Connector/J - Mapping Java String to MySQL INT

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, mysql-connector

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) for Connector/J says that it can easily convert a MySQL INT to a Java String type. (That is, mapping from a result set to a Java type.)

But does this work the other way around? In other words, can you use a Java `String` in a prepared statement where MySQL expects an `INT`? Is this considered good/bad practice?

```
# pseudo-code
table EMPLOYEES 
(
    NAME VARCHAR(50)
    EMPLOYEE_NO INT(11)
)

// Java code
PreparedStatement prepStmt = 
    con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from EMPLOYEES where EMPLOYEE_NO=?");
prepStmt.setString(1, str);
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.execute(); // ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [javadoc of `setString(`)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) (my emphasis):

> Sets the designated parameter to the given Java String value. The
>   driver converts this to an **SQL VARCHAR or LONGVARCHAR** value (depending
>   on the argument's size relative to the driver's limits on VARCHAR
>   values) when it sends it to the database.

Meaning this **might** not work, although it probably will (I suppose an int is represented just like a string when sent), but if things change that might not be the case. Either way, I do not regard it as good practice as there might be non-integer values in a String.

Instead, use:

```
prepStmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(str));
```

and handle `NumberFormatException` as you see fit.

---

Additionally the following line is invalid as `execute()` returns a `boolean` value.:

```
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.execute();
```

Instead, you can use:

```
if (prepStmt.execute()) {
    ResultSet rs = prepStmt.getResultSet();
}
```

or

```
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a good point. I guess the JavaDoc says it all. For some reason I was hunting for the Connector/J JavaDoc (I had an easier time finding its source code) but should have just looked at the specification interface instead.

Comment: Yes, the code was just for demonstration purposes, I should have written executeQuery.